# Jest not covering decorator function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs, code-coverage

I want to cover the folowing code usingjest:

```
    @Debounce(100)
    private checkDataToPositionInStep(): void {
        
        const proposalConsultData = this.proposalConsultResponseStore.get();

        if(proposalConsultData?.documentProposalData?.length > 1) {
            this.fullScreenLoaderService.hideLoader();
            this.router.navigate(['proposta-enviada']);
            return;
        }

        if(proposalConsultData?.warrantyData?.plateUf) {
            this.fullScreenLoaderService.hideLoader();
            this.router.navigate(['upload']);
        }

        if(proposalConsultData?.bankData?.branchCode) {
            this.fullScreenLoaderService.hideLoader();
            this.scrollService.next(STEP_ACCORDION.DADOS_GARANTIA.STEP);
            this.stepperService.next(STEP_ACCORDION.DADOS_GARANTIA.ID);
            return;
        }
        
        this.fullScreenLoaderService.hideLoader();
        this.scrollService.next(STEP_ACCORDION.DADOS_BANCARIOS.STEP);
        this.stepperService.next(STEP_ACCORDION.DADOS_BANCARIOS.ID);
        return;
    }
```

And de debounce decorator is like this:

```
export function Debounce(timeout: number): Function {
    return function (target, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        const original = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = function debounce(...args) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                original.apply(this, args);
            }, timeout);
        }
        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

When i run `npm run:coverage` all lines that are below decorators are not covering. Is there anyway to cover this lines ?

I just tried to call the checkDataToPositionStep method like this:

```
it('Should call checkDataToPositionInStep with only bankData', () => {ons
    const = proposalConsultMock = <any> {
      bankData: {
        branchCode: '01901'
      }
    };
    (facade as any).checkDataToPositionInStep(proposalConsultMock );
  });
```

And i thought that jest should cover the checkDataToPositionStep method.

Comment: Are you sure your Debounce decorator even works properly? It doesn't seem to return the result or even debounce the method.

Comment: Yes, it works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys, i found the solution using `jest.useFakeTimers()` and `jest.runAllTimers();`. The problem was with the setTimeout. The following code now is covering the checkDataToPositionInStep method.

```
 proposalConsultMock = <any> {
  documentProposalData: [{
    tpDocumentoProposta: 149
},{
    tpDocumentoProposta: 90
  }],
};

jest.useFakeTimers();
setTimeout(() => {
  (facade as any).checkDataToPositionInStep(proposalConsultMock);
}, 1000);
jest.runAllTimers();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an advice... ideally you shouldn't care about coverage itself, you want to be sure things get tested. And with that in mind, if you want to be sure that Debounce decorator is  tested, you can create a set of unit tests specifically for it.

### UPDATE

I just want to clarify, when I say "you shouldn't care about coverage itself", I don't mean you shouldn't care about code coverage, it's a really important metric to keep an eye on. But coverage does not always mean you're testing everything. Just be careful about it.

```
import { Debounce } from './Debouncefile';

describe('Debounce', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    // Arrange
    const debounceFunction = Debounce(60);

    // Act
    const result = debounceFunction(params...);

    // Assert
    expect(result).toBe(something);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello @Fernando Gallardo, thanks for your answer. Absolutely you are correct ! But in this case i have one file that tests the debounce decorator called debounce.spec.ts, and this file ensures that debounce works properly. But i have to cover 80% of my code, and if i could cover the checkDataToPositionInStep method the percentage of coverage will increase greatly, so that's my problem.

Comment: Ooohh I got that totally wrong. I thought you were missing coverage IN the decorator. Now that we are in the same page, your issue is probably the timeout inside the decorator (your test is finishing before the decorator ends running), probably the best option is to use jest.mock to mock the decorator function, I'm on my phone right now, but I'll add an answer with and example in a bit.

Comment: No problem my friend, i answer the solution that i got it and you were totally correct. The problem was with the setTimeout, the test was finishing before the decorator ends running. Thanks a lot for your help =)

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**:
Are you missing an `expect(...)` call ? such as

```js
    expect(
      (facade as any).checkDataToPositionInStep(proposalConsultMock)
    ).not.toThrowError();
```

**Secondly**:
Decorators should be tested separately from your main components. So that you have both the `checkDataToPositionInStep` function tested and also the returned function from `Debounce` in another test file:

```js
it('should do something', () => {
    // Create your instance
    const debounceFunction = Debounce(60);

    // Execute your function
    const result = debounceFunction(params...);

    // Expect a correct result
    expect(result).toBe(something);
  });
```

You might also want to check that your test file is correctly included in the coverage configuration.

**Finally**, I disagree with @facundo's advice on not caring about test coverage. It depends on the context and for code quality reasons you probably want to make sure that a percentage of your code is well tested while also avoiding software regressions.

Comment: Hey there! Maybe I chose my words poorly, what I tried to say is: code coverage is an awesome metric to keep in mind, but it does not mean that you're testing your code properly. (like in this case, if the code coverage report says "Debounce is 100% covered" but you don't have individual tests for it, there's something wrong.

I'll update my answer, I don't want to give people that kind of advice, I'm pro code coverage lol

Comment: Hello @SebastienH, thanks for your answer. I have one file called debounce.spec.ts that make the unit tests for this function works perfectely. But my problem is just to coverage the checkDataToPositionInStep. Jest is not covering this method because the debounce decorator, if i remove this decorator jest covers this method.